# Is it safe to delete a parent branch after a pull request merges that parent?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm using a Shared Repository model on GitHub. I made a feature branch A, pushed some changes to the remote origin, then created a pull request. I wanted to make more changes based on A, so made a new branch, B, from A. After pushing more edits, I created another pull request for B.

The pull request for A was accepted. So 'git pull origin master' then made my local master include A.

What do I do with branch A, given that it has a child branch, B?

I see that

```
$ git checkout B
$ git diff origin/master --
```

no longer includes the A diffs, as expected.

• So can I delete branch A without affecting B? After the accepted pull request, I see the A commit history in master.

• Will B then reparent to master?

• What will the effect be, if any, on the existing GitHub pull request for B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; dvcs commits work like a virus

A "branch" in Git is merely a [DAG of changesets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) in which the HEAD commit (on that branch) is accessed via the branch name. If another repository has been given (ie. 'pushed' or 'pulled') the committed changesets, then they now exist in that repository as well. *Deleting the local commits will have no bearing on the commits already applied to the other repositories.*

For the pull from upstream to have worked, the root for the changeset "branch" DAG must have already existed on the upstream target. Thus the pulled data is really the `root_from_upstream->commit(s)->head_at_pull` changesets: the pull from the upstream repository caused it to apply the changesets to itself, all the way to the head of the branch (which is a particular revision), at the time of the pull request.

Deleting (or, perhaps better, 'closing') the local branch *doesn't* remove any changesets; it simply makes them unreachable via *that* branch name.

Even if commits were 'purged' from the local Git repository (or 'stripped' in Mercurial parlance), *the commit changesets still exist in the other repositories to which they were pushed to (or pulled into)*.

If a pull from the origin is done the changesets will be fetched as required to complete the DAG. However the "branch" itself is not re-created because such a name was a local artifact that has since been discarded.

---

> So can I delete branch A without affecting B? After the accepted pull request, I see the A commit history in master.

Yes. The local branch can be deleted if it no longer serves a useful purpose. The commits have already propagated out to another repository - and even if not, *the changesets would still be part of the DAG formed by branch 'B'*.

> Will B then reparent to master?

No. A branch name simply identifies a particular commit of the changeset graph. Deleting branch 'A' does not affect the changesets/DAG and will have no impact on 'B'. *There is absolutely no implicit reparenting.*

> What will the effect be, if any, on the existing GitHub pull request for B?

Nothing.

---

This is why, like email message, it is important to tidy and organize commits *before* pushing them (or having them pulled). Once released into the wild there is no trivial way to capture the changesets.

---

Mercurial works a little bit differently but the 'tip' of any particular Hg branch works similarly to a Git branch: it identifies a particular commit in the changeset DAG that represents the current branch HEAD.

Comment: Thank you for answering the individual questions directly after giving the the principles.

Answer (score 2):

Let's presume the sequence of events was thus:

```
git checkout -b A
git commit
git commit
git commit
git checkout -b B
git commit
git commit
git checkout master
git commit
git merge A
```

That would give you a picture that looks like this:

[image]

In this scenario, **A is perfectly safe to delete**, since the work you've based B on is included in master.

B won't automatically have a new parent, though; you should consider [rebasing your branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) against master.  This will give the history the appearance of having always been after the commits in master, and will reduce the noise and confusion of your work later on.

Think of it like a [Dictator and Lieutenants](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Dictator-and-Lieutenants-Workflow) workflow.  Upstream should always represent the canonical source of truth, and your work should always be rebased against it.

Comment: Nit: If A is a parent of B then it is *always* 'safe' to delete A, excepting if someone wishes to use the name (such a not-yet-pulled PR).

Answer (score 0):

So I found that I can easily demonstrate user2864740's and Makoto's answer to the second question with a script, shown below.

Here's the answer:

```
+ git log --graph --oneline --branches
* a392a9d branch_B change_b2 commit
* 7c29ca6 initial branch_B change_b1 commit
| *   30591f8 merge branch_A into master
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 34a1162 branch_A change_a2 commit
* | 2ad533b initial branch_A change_a1 commit
| * 67941a1 mergable change in master
|/
* 36d7364 initial master commit
+ git branch -d branch_A
Deleted branch branch_A (was 34a1162).
+ git log --graph --oneline --branches
* a392a9d branch_B change_b2 commit
* 7c29ca6 initial branch_B change_b1 commit
| *   30591f8 merge branch_A into master
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 34a1162 branch_A change_a2 commit
* | 2ad533b initial branch_A change_a1 commit
| * 67941a1 mergable change in master
|/
* 36d7364 initial master commit
```

It shows that, indeed, deleting A has no effect on the tree.

Here's the script, which others may find useful for testing git sequences:

```
#!/bin/bash

d=_test_`date +"%y%m%d%H%M"`
mkdir $d
cd $d
echo Testing in `pwd`

set -x  #echo on

# init and make master
git init
touch f
echo master1 >> f
git add .
git commit -a -m'initial master commit'

# make branch A
git checkout -b branch_A
echo change_a1 >> f
git commit -a -m'initial branch_A change_a1 commit'
echo change_a2 >> f
git commit -a -m'branch_A change_a2 commit'
cat f

# commit on master so we can see the branching structure
git checkout master
echo change_a1 >> f
echo change_a2 >> f
git commit -a -m'mergable change in master'

# make branch B
git checkout branch_A
git checkout -b branch_B
echo change_b1 >> f
git commit -a -m'initial branch_B change_b1 commit'
echo change_b2 >> f
git commit -a -m'branch_B change_b2 commit'

# commit on branch_A so we can see the branching structure
#git checkout branch_A
#echo change_a3 >> f
#git commit -a -m'another commit on a'

# Where's B on the tree?
git log --graph --oneline --branches

# merge branch A into master
git checkout master
git merge branch_A -m'merge branch_A into master'
cat f

# Where's B on the tree?
git log --graph --oneline --branches

# delete branch A
git branch -d branch_A

# Where's B on the tree?
git log --graph --oneline --branches
```